Change value when change dir in Laravel
I have a Laravel app that uses two (2) languages, and in my language file, I put dir= rtl and ltr.
Then in my layout I used this:
dir="{{ trans('front.lng') }}"
Now, I want to make variables show depending on dir value.
This is my code now:
<div class="col">
    <label for="profession_id"> <i class=""></i> {{ trans('front.p2_s_prochoose') }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="profession_id">
        <option value="">{{ trans('front.p2_s_allpro') }}</option>
        @foreach ($professions as $profession)
            @if ($profession->id == $profession_id)
                <option value="{{ $profession->id }}" selected>
                    {{ $profession->title_ar }}
                </option>
            @else
                <option value="{{ $profession->id }}">{{ $profession->title_ar }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <label for="profession_id"> <i class=""></i> {{ trans('front.p2_s_prochoose') }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="profession_id">
        <option value="">{{ trans('front.p2_s_allpro') }}</option>
        @foreach ($professions as $profession)
            @if ($profession->id == $profession_id)
                <option value="{{ $profession->id }}" selected>
                    @if ({{ trans('front.lng') == 'RTL' }})
                        {{ $profession->title_ar }}
                    @else
                        {{ $profession->title }}
                    @endif
                </option>
            @else
                <option value="{{ $profession->id }}">{{ $profession->title_ar }}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

And nothing happened.

U can use the tinker and do >trans('front.lng') to show the expected result.

You cant use curly brackets inside the blade if/else/foreach/switch statements.
This wont work:
@if ({{ trans('front.lng') == 'RTL' }})

This should:
@if (trans('front.lng') === 'RTL')


not working all

ok help yourself. If you cant even get the syntax right there is nothing I can do here.
